# The TryIt page proposes only a subject name. How testing with http://wso2.org/claims/role for example

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm running the wso2is-4.6.0
I've created a policy like allowing a user with a specific role to access a resource.

When I TryIt, the wso2is manager just propose me a Subject Name (urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id). I've seen in previous version of wso2Is [see here](http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.fr/2011/12/entitlement-service-xacml-pdp-as-web.html) that it was possible to define a Subject Attribute Name (in my case it would be http://wso2.org/claims/role).

The result is that I can't test my request with the current version as the attributeId generated by wso2 tryIt tool refer to a subject-id where I need a  http://wso2.org/claims/role

Any way to have this Tryit page more customizable ?

Thanks for your help and support

Regards
Vpl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TryIt is a simple tool that you can create the XACML request. It can not support all options that are available. However when its some to new version,  It seems to be that attribute Id selection has been removed.  But you can file the attribute values and create the sample XACML request in XML view.  Then you would find that the attribute id of created XACML request would be `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id`. Therefore you can easily modify it to `http://wso2.org/claims/role` and try out the policy.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Yes, this is finally what I did and it worked Thanks very much for your help.